# Headless UI "leave" transition not working in React

Tags: reactjs, animation, transition, tailwind-css, headless

My navbar is setup such that on state change the hamburger menu opens and closes. While the `enter` animation works perfectly, the `leave` doesn't. My animation is a smooth slide in and slide out, but only the slide in works whereas on leave it just closes normally.

```
const NavbarMenu = ({ isOpen, menuClick }) => {
  return (
    <Transition appear={true} show={isOpen}>
      <Transition.Child
        class="flex flex-col bg-yellow-700 fixed top-0 right-0 p-5 z-20 w-1/2 h-full transition ease-in-out duration-300"
        enter="transition-opacity ease-in-out duration-700"
        enterFrom="translate-x-full"
        enterTo="translate-x-0"
        leave="transition-opacity ease-out duration-700"
        leaveFrom="opacity-100"
        leaveTo="opacity-0"
      >
        <Exit className="text-yellow-100 w-1/6" onClick={() => menuClick()} />
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-4 mt-10 font-poppins font-bold text-xl text-yellow-100">
          <span>About</span>
          <span>About</span>
          <span>About</span>
        </div>
      </Transition.Child>
    </Transition>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your leave transition is missing the translate-x classes.

You probably also want to add the opacity transition to the enter animation.

This should work:

```
const NavbarMenu = ({ isOpen, menuClick }) => {
  return (
    <Transition appear={true} show={isOpen}>
      <Transition.Child
        class="flex flex-col bg-yellow-700 fixed top-0 right-0 p-5 z-20 w-1/2 h-full transition duration-700"
        enter="ease-in-out"
        enterFrom="translate-x-full opacity-0"
        enterTo="translate-x-0 opacity-100"
        leave="ease-out"
        leaveFrom="translate-x-0 opacity-100"
        leaveTo="translate-x-full opacity-0"
      >
        <Exit className="text-yellow-100 w-1/6" onClick={() => menuClick()} />
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-4 mt-10 font-poppins font-bold text-xl text-yellow-100">
          <span>About</span>
          <span>About</span>
          <span>About</span>
        </div>
      </Transition.Child>
    </Transition>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Most often when "leave transitions" doesn't work it's because it unmounts before the transition ends. To work around that you need a "between state" that is triggered when the Transition is in show mode. Then create a useEffect that listens to this state, and set a setTimeout that does the actual unmount of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, just delay the execution of set state to 0ms so the transition can trigger the leave property. I don't have a logical explanation but this worked smoothly.

```
    const NavbarMenu = ({ isOpen, menuClick }) => {
  return (
    <Transition appear={true} show={isOpen}>
      <Transition.Child
        class="flex flex-col bg-yellow-700 fixed top-0 right-0 p-5 z-20 w-1/2 h-full transition ease-in-out duration-300"
        enter="transition-opacity ease-in-out duration-700"
        enterFrom="translate-x-full"
        enterTo="translate-x-0"
        leave="transition-opacity ease-out duration-700"
        leaveFrom="opacity-100"
        leaveTo="opacity-0"
      >
        <Exit className="text-yellow-100 w-1/6" 
              onClick={() => 
                setTimeout(() => {
                    menuClick();
                }, 0);
              } />
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-4 mt-10 font-poppins font-bold text-xl text-yellow-100">
          <span>About</span>
          <span>About</span>
          <span>About</span>
        </div>
      </Transition.Child>
    </Transition>
  );
};
```